# Django geoip2 + Maxmind working locally, but not in production?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, geoip2

I'm able to get a response object and render it to the page locally, but on my live site it doesn't work.

I'm using Maxmind's binary database, which is the `GeoLite2-City.mmdb` file in my project folder.

This also works in my website's Ubuntu 16.04 terminal:

```
import geoip2.database
reader = geoip2.database.Reader('/home/jake/project-main/project/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)
location_lookup_response = reader.city(ip)
print(location_lookup_resonse)
```

However, it doesn't work on the site. Any thoughts here are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py` file, you should have the `GEOIP_PATH` set to the directory which contains the `GeoLite2-*.mmdb` files. The documentation for that [can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/#module-django.contrib.gis.geoip2).

Once the `*.mmdb` files are in the `GEOIP_PATH`, you should be able to find them using the django shell:

```sh
$ python manage.py shell
```

```py
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> print(settings.GEOIP_PATH)
'/path/to/geoip-mmdb-files'

>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(settings.GEOIP_PATH)
['GeoLite2-City.mmdb', 'GeoLite2-Country.mmdb']

>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
>>> g = GeoIP2()
>>> g.country('google.com')
{'country_code': 'US', 'country_name': 'United States'}
```

Comment: Thanks @damon. Once I switched to this method it worked. It turns out that it was due the Chinese characters included in the response object, where it lists Chinese and other non-English versions of place names. `'ascii' codec can't encode characters ...`